# modifying the bodyParser size in sails.js without having to modify the sails library sourcefile

Tags: sails.js

I modified the bodyParser option size for posting huge strings through input forms in sails.
I did it the following way: 
I went to: node_modules/sails/lib/express/index.js
And then I replaced the default bodyParser  :

```
bodyParser = sails.config.express.bodyParser();
```

by

```
bodyParser = sails.config.express.bodyParser({limit: 8248242});
```

I works, but I suppose there must be an easier way to do it via parameters or something...
I tried to create an express.js file in the config folder like in https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/8249181

but it does not seem to recognise the express module...

Any advice about what would be the best way to change the bodyParser size limit via some kind of parameter? 
Cheers!

Comment: The `express.js` config is (for the moment) the right solution.  Did you `npm install express` to your project first?

Comment: Ah. Good point, indeed... I had not realised that express was not explicitely added to the package.json and that sails has its own internal separate express distribution. I added express in package.json, and an express.js as follow in the config folder: 
`   module.exports.express = {
       express: {
     bodyParser: function () {
       return require('express').bodyParser({
      limit: 8248242
       })
     }
      }
   };` and it now works after npm install... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Scott! I don't know how this voting system works, but I am grateful for your help!! I had not realised that express was not explicitely added to the package.json and that sails has its own internal separate express distribution. I added express in package.json, and an express.js as follow in the config folder:
    module.exports.express = { 
       express: { 
          bodyParser: function () { 
             return require('express').bodyParser({ limit: 8248242 }) 
          } 
       } 
    };

and it now works after npm install... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The expected awswer won't work with Sails v10.

Here's the fix that worked for me.

You need to install the body-parser NPM

```
npm install body-parser
```

then add

```
bodyParser:  function () { return require('body-parser')({ limit: 8248242 }) }
```

into config/http.js

Comment: I tried this but the request just hangs up, never even reaching the controller. Any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

This now works for me in Sails 1.2.3; specifically, using the example `bodyParser` in the default `config/http.js`:

```
...
bodyParser: (function _configureBodyParser(){
  var skipper = require('skipper');
  var middlewareFn = skipper({
    // strict: true,
    limit: '10mb',
  });
  return middlewareFn;
})(),
...
```